# "Edit with Idle" appears when I right click a python file, yet does not work. Also, python files show the wrong icon

Tags: python

My problem: http://imgur.com/a/a3D30

...I can, however, open Idle manually, and then open the file. But this is a hassle.

Another small thing. What is wrong with my python file's icon?

How can I fix this? Thanks lads.

Answer (score 0):

- Find the file in your documents, click on it and then select the drop down arrow next to the open button.
- Select choose default program. then click browse. This should open up your program files, at the top select the file before program files (Hard to explain but it should be some sort of drive, like a C: drive).
- Then click the python folder, then the lib folder. Then scroll down to idlelib. In there should be a windows batch file called idle. double click on that and then click Ok.

It should now automatically open python when you double click a python file. Sorry for the long winded explanation.

Comment: Use "Steps" to describe what you intend to explain in order to make it easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically with the file association.
Follow the step shown below to correct your file association.

Right click on the python (*.py) file and select properties. The following dialog will appear
[image]

Click on the **Change** button. In the next dialog shown below
[image]
click on **Browse** and in the list select **IDLE** and see if it works.
If it does not please post a comment